# How to export a random entry in a database to a word table using C#

Tags: c#, database, ms-word

I am trying to build a windows form application that compiles quiz questions into a pre constructed word table from a database. I am struggling to find the right code to pull a random line from my database (question to one cell, answer to another cell in my table). The idea is to have it automated from a button click event. Through lots of Googling I have figured out how to call up the word document containing the table but not how to write to it from the database.

Comment: Well what have you tried? A little more information would probably help

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to try to clarify your situation:

1. You currently have a database of questions and corresponding answers.
2. You want to have a click event that on a button that will pull a random question and answer to prompt the user.
3. Then write to a word document the question and answer in whatever order those questions have been chosen.

Here's how I would go about doing this:

1. Start getting these in List variables
   These kinds of situations are easier if you can contain data from a database in variables from the beginning rather than trying to use data straight from the database (that might be a personal thing I enjoy but it might help you as well).
2. Start playing around with word.interop libraries. If I remember correctly, you have to call up the Word App, then call the word document, then write lines individually.  Google will help plenty here.

Hopefully this helped

Comment: No the program needs to pull a line from the database which include a the question and answer from the same ID line but write them to separate boxes in a word table so you have the question in one box and the answer in another. The table is already constructed and I have written the code to call the table up. I have googled lots about word automation but have not found any about writing from a database.

Comment: Are you using a SQL database? If so you just need to use a select statement to pull your question and answer from it and proceed to manage the data from there. Select statements normally look something like this: "SELECT question,answer FROM QUIZ WHERE [ID] LIKE 'your variable'"